# IP Camera Ethernet Direct Connection

Tags: ubuntu

I've been struggling with this for the past 12 hours.  I am trying to connect my IP Camera to my RPI running ubuntu that's on a cellular hotspot wifi for internet. I cant seem to get my camera to become discoverable.

Cellular Hotspot <-(wifi)-> Raspberry Pi 4 <-(ethernet) IP Camera

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.21.21  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.21.255
        inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fe66:558  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:a6:32:66:05:58  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2584  bytes 217550 (217.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 21  bytes 1398 (1.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 58143  bytes 3733984 (3.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 58143  bytes 3733984 (3.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fe66:559  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2600:1011:b02d:a13d:dea6:32ff:fe66:559  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether dc:a6:32:66:05:59  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 16045  bytes 11275233 (11.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11197  bytes 4945492 (4.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: false
            addresses: [192.168.21.21/24]
            optional: true
    version: 2
    wifis:
        wlan0:
            access-points:
                Verizon:
                    password: ''
            dhcp4: false
            addresses: [192.168.1.2/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.1.1
            nameservers:
              addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
            optional: false
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you swapped out cables on the camera?  Do you know the camera's MAC address?  Have you tried pinging the broadcast address on the ethernet network to see what responds: `ping 192.168.21.255 -b` and then using `arp` to look for the camera's MAC address?  As Number Five said, 'Need more input'.

Comment: @serialhobbyist  i know  the cameras MAC. its running on a crossover cable.

Comment: You only answered one of my questions, so the rest stand.  In addition, if you haven't swapped out the cable for a known-working one (as it you literally just tried it on something else and it worked), put something else at the camera-end and make sure you can see that.

Comment: You appear to have configured your network to use static IP addresses.  Most devices are configured out of the box to get an IP address from a DHCP server (do you know what that is?).  Have you done anything to give the camera access to a DHCP service?  If not, have you configured an IP address on the camera?  You need to edit your question to give us more information because there is not enough to go on, here.